# How do I draw vertical lines on a horizontal bar chart with chart.js?

Tags: charts, chart.js

I want to create a bar chart which also describe the frequency of activities within the year just like this.
[Chart with vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lFSO.png) 
How can I get it with Chart.Js?
I have no idea how to achieve the result like the image attached. Thank you.
Here is my code.

```js
window.onload = function() {
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
      window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
          labels: ["Company A", "Company B", "Company C", "Company D", "Company E"],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Company and Activities',
            data: [[1988,2006],[1998,2015],[2004,2006],[1994,2008],[1986,2007]],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.9)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.9)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.9)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.9)',           
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.9)'               
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
            display:false,
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Company and Activities'
          }
        }
      });
    };
```

```css
    canvas {
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bars</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="100"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, kindly add some code by editing your question so that we can understand what you have tried so far and on that we can give our inputs or answers.

Comment: @wahabmemon I am sorry for late reply. I already edited my post.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You cant do this with default chart.js, you will need to write a custom plugin for it to achieve this: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/plugins.html

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is using the [chartjs-timeline-plugin](https://github.com/fanthos/chartjs-chart-timeline)

Comment: Thank you guys. I am not expert in javascript. So writing a custom plugin will take me a lot of time to finish. I think better try to use timeline plugin.